# How can the Scarlet Witch break the Mind Stone?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

The Infinity stones have existed since the origin of the Universe.

Since the Mind stone is so powerful how can the Scarlet Witch break it in *Avengers: Infinity War*?

Comment: By magic.....!!!

Comment: But how can she break the source of power of the universe? she is a human not an immortal.

Comment: She got powers from the same stone, so she is not anymore a normal human being

Comment: "This gave creative freedom to the writers, as it actually meant that [her powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarlet_Witch#Powers_and_abilities) could be used for any purpose required by the plot."

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You know how it's possible to shatter a wine glass by making it vibrate at *exactly* the right frequency? That's the exact same principle Wanda used to shatter the Mind Stone. Yes, it may be an immensely powerful crystal, formed in the very heart of the Big Bang... but it's still a crystal. It's just as vulnerable to resonant frequencies as glass.

I believe Vision explains this when he first brings up the idea of Wanda shattering the Mind Stone.

> I've been giving a good deal of thought to this entity in my head about its nature. But also, its composition.
>
> I think if it were exposed to a sufficiently powerful energy source, **something, very similar to its own signature, perhaps...**
>
> Its molecular integrity could fail.

Answer (score 49):

Because her powers are the same energy as the Mind Stone.

As seen in *Age of Ultron*, Wanda and Pietro were given their powers by von Strucker, using Loki's Scepter (which contained the Mind Stone). Because of this, Wanda is the only person who could destroy the stone.

The relevant quote from Infinity War comes from Vision:

> I've been giving a good deal of thought to this entity in my head, about its nature, but also its composition. I think if it were exposed to a sufficiently powerful energy source, something **very similar to its own signature** perhaps, its molecular integrity could fail.