# Can Wanda destroy all the Infinity Stones?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Saw this [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89609/how-can-the-scarlet-witch-break-the-mind-stone) about *Avengers: Infinity War* and the accepted answer says that Wanda is the only one who can destroy the **MIND** stone. But what about the other stones? Can Wanda destroy them all to get rid of them forever?

Comment: I think this will just be opinion based as we only KNOW that Wanda could destroy the Mind Stone.  We do not know that the other stones do not have an energy signature which is the same as or similar enough to the Mind Stone that Wanda could destroy them - this may be explained in the next Avengers film however.

Comment: In Avengers, Lokis scepter is used against the tesseract, on the logic that they can't defend against its own energy signature. It's later revealed that the scepter housed the mind stone, and the tesseract housed the space stone. If her energy signature is identical to the mind stones, she can destroy (at least) the space stone as well.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen, because I think that rather than a POB close this is more accurately a duplicate of : https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89609/how-can-the-scarlet-witch-break-the-mind-stone/89612#89612

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Wanda was able to destroy only the Mind Stone.

As Vision explains, she has the same energy signature as the Mind Stone, because she got her powers from it **this** is why she was able to destroy the **Mind** stone.